# Retrieve HTTP POST request parameters (sent from flex app) in python

Tags: python, apache-flex

I am sending the parameters from flex application through HTTP POST request to Python/PSP script. I am able to call PSP script from flex app using HTTP POST request, but i am not able to use/retrieve these parameters in Python/PSP.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the `cgi` module from the standard library. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#module-cgi).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but is'nt the CGI script used to process the user input submitted through an HTML form only. Cn it be used for form made in flex app also?

Comment: Nothing to do with HTML forms. If you're POSTing to the interface, `cgi.FieldStorage()` will allow you access to the data.

Comment: thanx..i got it done..and how can some info from python script be sent back to flex app/